# I GET ERROR incompatible types required: String found: Tsubsicode

Tags: java

```
If (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("party")) {
// FileWriter.wrfile( "0 ");

    party = request.getParameter("party");  
    // if (jsonData.isJsonObject()){
//  Tsubsicode tsubsicode = gson.fromJson(jsonData.getAsJsonObject("party"), Tsubsicode.class );
    SubsiService ss = new SubsiService();
    sub = ss.getActivitycd(party);
    retval.add("sub", utls.getJsonElement(sub, Boolean.TRUE));
 }
```

THIS IS MY CODE , I GET ERROR

```
incompatible types
required: String
found:    Tsubsicode
```

IN MY SERVICE CLASS , I HAVE DEFINED AS

```
public class SubsiService {
public Tsubsicode getActivitycd(String party) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace...it should have line no causing the issue and all.

Comment: i get Error on this Line  Sub = ss.getActivitycd(party);

Answer (score 0):

Check type of **party**, which is initialised at

```
party = request.getParameter("party");
```

I susspect it is of type **Tsubsicode**. You are passing it to getActivitycd(String) method of SubsiService, which is expecting string but it is complaining that it is getting **Tsubsicode** instead **String** as per error message.